# Text Scraping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a dynamic text which looks something like this

```
my_text = "address ae fae daq ad, 1231 asdas  landline 213121233 -123    mobile 513121233 cell (132) -142-3127  
           email sdasdas@gmail.com , sdasd as@yahoo.com - ewqas@gmail.com"
```

The text starts with an 'address'. As soon as we see 'address' we need to scrape everything from there until either 'landline'/'mobile'/'cell' appears. From there on, we want to scrape when all the phone text (without altering spaces in between). We start from the first occurrence of either 'landline'/'mobile'/'cell' and stop as soon as we find 'email' appear.
Finally we scrape the email part (without altering spaces in between)

'landline'/'mobile'/'cell' can appear in any order and sometimes some may not appear.
For example, the text could have looked like this as well.

```
my_text = "address ae fae daq ad, 1231 asdas  
           cell (132) -142-3127 landline 213121233 -123     
           email sdasdas@gmail.com , sdasd as@yahoo.com - ewqas@gmail.com"
```

There's a little more engineering that needs to be done to form arrays of subtext contained in address, phones and email text.
Subtexts of addresses are always separated with commas (,).
Subtexts of emails can be separated with commas (,) or hyphens (-).

My output should be a JSON dictionary which looks something like this:

```
resultant_dict = {
    addresses: [{
        address: "ae fae daq ad"
    }, {
        address: "1231 asdas"
    }],
    phones: [{
        number: "213121233 -123",
        kind: "landline"
    }, {
        number: "513121233",
        kind: "mobile"
    }, {
        number: "(132 -142-3127",
        kind: "cell"
    }],
    emails: [{
        email: "sdasdas@gmail.com",
        connector: ""
    }, {
        email: "sdasd as@yahoo.com",
        connector: ","
    }, {
        email: "ewqas@gmail.com",
        connector: "-"
    }]
}
```

I am trying to achieve this thing using regular expressions or any other way in JavaScript. I can't figure out how to write this as I am a novice programmer.

Comment: what is `sdasd ` ? inside the email? is it even a valid email address?

Comment: sdasd as@yahoo.com is the email id entered by the user, which has erroneous space in it.

Comment: we can do a solution by trimming the space away. But I would like to get the whole thing with the space as the email

Comment: Can you show your best try? JS, regexp, anything?

Comment: Also, in your dictionary why don't you use simply `addresses = []` instead of the useless Object `address:` ?

Comment: Why two different separators for emails (" , " and " - ")? What the hell is this string?? x-D

Comment: @wawawared probably inside a weird composer, additional emails were separated by `-` as opposed to new properties where `,` are used or a property name (without the `,`)

Comment: Update (closer to your requirements): http://stackoverflow.com/a/32413281/1636522. The values won't contain any comma or dash surrounded by spaces hopefully :-|

Comment: There needs to be some validation going on before the text becomes such a mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit twisted... Plural for map keys, section names as a key for each item... Moreover, what about a dedicated array for each "kind" of phone? We can get the expected result for sure, but it's seems pretty useless at first glance. Anyway, here a starting point:

```js
var str = 'address ae fae daq ad, 1231 asdas  landline 213121233 -123    mobile 513121233 cell (132) -142-3127             email sdasdas@gmail.com , sdasd as@yahoo.com - ewqas@gmail.com';

// find sections

var s = 'address|landline|mobile|cell|email';
var reSections = new RegExp('(' + s + ').*?(?=' + s + '|$)', 'g');
var slices = str.match(reSections);

document.body.innerHTML += (
  '<b>Step 1 - Find sections</b>' +
  '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(slices, 0, 2) + '</pre>\n'
);

// make a map

var map = {
  address: [],
  phone: [],
  email: []
};

var reTrim = /^\s+|\s+$/g;
var reSanitize = /\s+(-|,)\s+/g;
var reSection = /^(\w+)(.*)$/;

slices.forEach(function (section) {
  var m = section.match(reSection);
  var category = 'email address'.indexOf(m[1]) !== -1 ? m[1] : 'phone';
  var values = m[2].replace(reSanitize, ',').split(',');
  map[category] = map[category].concat(values.map(function (value) {
    return { kind: m[1], value: value.replace(reTrim, '') };
  }));
});

document.body.innerHTML += (
  '<b>Step 2 - Make a map</b>' +
  '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(map, 0, 2) + '</pre>\n'
);
```

Comment: `cell : {kind : "cell"}` :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I know, that's why I call this a "starting point" x-D

Answer (score -2):

A bit hackish solution but works.
Try this :
mymap={};a=str;keys=["address","cell","landline","email"];for(var k in keys){a=a.replace(keys[k],"##"+keys[k])}; console.log(a);b=a.split("##");for(var f in b){x=b[f].split(" ");mymap[x[0]]=x.slice(1).join(" ")}; console.log(mymap);

mymap will contain all the fields which you are looking for. You can parse it to create JSON in your format.